# What is the best way to calculate month difference between two dates which have format like yyyyMM. in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my python df, I have columns MTH, old_dt

```
MTH     old_dt
201901  2018-03-01
201902  2017-02-20
201903  2016-05-12
```

to calculate the month difference between two columns, I use the following python code

```
df['mth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MTH'], format='%Y%m')

df=df.assign(
    dif=
    (df.mth.dt.year - df.old_dt.dt.year) * 12 +
    (df.mth.dt.month - df.old_dt.dt.month)+1
)
```

The result will be integer, which is exactly what I want.

Now since my dataset is huge (more than 1 billion records), I decide to move to pyspark. but Not sure how does it work. I searched online and see a function month_difference, but it seems not look like what I want.

Thanks for any help, and Thanks Jens for the editting.

My expected output is :

```
MTH     old_dt       dif
201901  2018-03-01   11
201902  2017-02-20   25
201903  2016-05-12   35
```

Comment: Please add expected output?

Comment: please see the edited version, thanks

Answer (score 1):

will this work please? I was not able to open my AE to test

```
    def mth_interval(df):
      df = df.withColumn("mth", F.to_date('MTH', 'yyyyMM'))
      df = df.withColumn('month_diff', ((F.year("mth")-F.year("old_dt")) *12+ 
      (F.month("mth")-F.month("old_dt"))+1)
    return df
```

thanks!

just tested and worked!

Comment: you have to import the pyspark functions first: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

Comment: thanks, you are right, I import everything at the beginning  and forgot to mention :)